# Script dependencies for post.js

Tags: jquery, metabox, core

I have already got the built in meta boxes displaying on the front, but some of them require the accompanying `wp-admin/js/post.js` to function correctly. I'd rather not rewrite anything here and just include what is already written. The problem is there are variables in the file which must be declared somewhere else, `postboxes` for example. Does anybody know where in the core files this file and/or it's dependencies are defined?

If anybody is wondering, this is part of a front end administration plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the dependency handling built into the script registration system you should only need ...

```
wp_enqueue_script('post');
```

... to load all of the required scripts, which is [exactly what the Core does](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L13).

But just loading the scripts isn't going to make everything work. That form is actually loaded by [`wp-admin/post.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/post.php#L198), which  `require`s [`wp-admin/admin.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/post.php#L12) which `include`s and `require`s other things, some of which `include` and `require` still more things. I am honestly not sure what all has to be done-- never been a fan of the "front end posting" idea-- but this is not a small project or a simple one.

I guess that does answer this question though:

> Does anybody know where in the core files this file and/or it's
>   dependencies are defined?

Comment: After playing around for a few hours last night, I came to the same conclusion. It would be far easier to write, and maintain, by just re-implementing what I need.

Comment: Took a look again and it seems what I thought was something not being included from my code is actually a not working for the real admin page either. Could you confirm? "New post/page" screen, "Categories" metabox, and try adding a new category. I get `TypeError: q.parsed is undefined` in the console. But the Ajax request is going through OK (the new category is added). On 6.3.1 btw.