# Custom jQuery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm trying to use this addon:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

to make it possible to edit a post date and time in the frontend before submitting it.

I'm registering my scripts like this:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

//TIMEPICKER
wp_enqueue_style( 'timepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css' );
wp_enqueue_script('timepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jqueryui-datepicker', ), '1.4.3' );

wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');

//LEAFLET
wp_enqueue_style( 'leaflet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/leaflet/leaflet.css' );
wp_enqueue_script('leaflet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/leaflet/leaflet.js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Integrated datepicker is working fine, but as I want to use the timepicker as well I get this error message:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

So I was wondering what causes this error. Is it maybe, because the addon uses $ instead of jQuery?

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Comment: You answered your own question with your last sentence.

Comment: I tried replacing all $ with jQuery in the addon but the result will stay the same

Comment: You know that the dependency array means that you don't have to load the dependencies explicitly? See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114419/21376 I am fairly sure the script is written in such a way that you don't need to replace `$`. Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: So what dependencies should I define? 
I am not sure if I can use this addon with wordpress or not.
http://www.citizen-science.at/wordpress/projekte/roadkill/eintrag-hinzufugen/

The field next to the date should initialize the datetimepicker.

Comment: When I delete the dependencies I get following error: `TypeError: $.ui is undefined`

Comment: You misunderstand. You don't need the individual `wp_enqueue_script`s for each dependency.

Comment: Oj so I just enqueue my custom script with all the depencies and get rid of the jquery stuff? I updated my question. Error still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your link 403's for me. I assume you're using the code I found here:

https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/blob/master/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Now, the $ thing is not a problem, that JS code library uses a proper $ wrapper, so it will work fine without modification.

The actual problem is a simple misspelling. Look at this line of code:

`wp_enqueue_script('timepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jqueryui-datepicker', ), '1.4.3' )`

That bit where you have `jqueryui-datepicker` should actually be `jquery-ui-datepicker`. Note the additional hyphen.

Look in `wp-includes/script-loader.php`, around line 163 or so, and you'll find where all the default scripts are named.